# function is not trigger when a tag is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help! i tried to call a function when an a tag is clicked.

```
<a href="<?php echo "javascript:pager('".$start."', 'search-inbox', '".$keyword."', 'prev')"; ?>" id="prev" class="pager-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left inbox-pager" id="prev"></i></a> 
<a href="<?php echo "javascript:pager('".$start."', 'search-inbox', '".$keyword."', 'next')"; ?>" id="next" class="pager-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right inbox-pager" id="next"></i></a>
```

in my script

```
function pager(start, searchKeyword, keyword, page){
    var pager = page;
    switch(pager){
        case "prev":
                if(start > 10 && start <= totalCount){
                start -= limit;
                if(start == 1 || start > 1){
                    loadMessages(start, searchKeyword, keyword);
                } else {
                    return;
                }                       
            }
            break;
        case "next":
            if(end < totalCount){
                start += limit;
                if(start < totalCount){
                    loadMessages(start, searchKeyword, keyword);
                } else if(start == totalCount){
                    loadMessages(start, searchKeyword, keyword);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    alert(pager);
}
```

this function is not trigger but when i omit the switch condition i can trigger the function.

```
function pager(start, searchKeyword, keyword, page){
    alert(page);
}
```

newbie here

Comment: Do you declared `totalCount`, `limit` as a variable? Any errors you got from console??

Comment: If the function only runs after removing the `switch` statement then obviously the `switch` contains some error(s). Do any errors display in the browser's dev console? (One thing you are doing wrong is passing the first argument as a string rather than a number, but although I would expect that to produce incorrect results for your "next" paging I wouldn't expect it to stop the function from running at all.)

Comment: Can't see the `end` variable declared either

Comment: If you just use a proper event handler instead, you don't have to echo code that belongs in the nineties.

Comment: @norlihazmey yes. totalCount, end and limit are global variables declared when the document is ready.

Comment: i tried to omit the if/elseif condition in the switch and it alerts.

Comment: OK, so that narrows down where the problem is, but still: please check the console for errors.

Comment: If you hit the `return` statement, it returns, the alert newer fires, maybe you should `break` it instead

Comment: no errors in the console.

Comment: if you declared global variable inside document.ready ,change it ,should declare in top of line ,outside of document.ready

Comment: i see the problem when i alert the start it results to 110. instead of 11 it results to 110. limit = 10

Comment: So in other words you're adding strings together, not numbers

Comment: sir why it adds as strings in the I passed integer in the function and limit is an integer. I also alert the limit it results to 10. please help

Comment: Well, `$start` is clearly a string, as it's in quotes when you echo it out, so doing `start += limit;` where `start` is a string, ends up still being a string.

Comment: thanks sir! i got it. in a link I enclose $start inside ' '. that is why I passed a string instead of an integer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the error I enclosed the $start inside single quotation(' ') so I passed a string instead of and integer.

```
<a href="<?php echo "javascript:pager(".$start.", 'search-sent', '".$keyword."', 'prev')"; ?>" id="prev-sent" class="pager-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left sent-pager" id="prev-sent"></i></a> 
<a href="<?php echo "javascript:pager(".$start.", 'search-sent', '".$keyword."', 'prev')"; ?>" id="next-sent" class="pager-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right sent-pager" id="next-sent"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach event listeners in your js file rather than inline in HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Attach event listeners
    $('.bigButton, #menuButton, #aboutButton').on({
    'click': fClick,
    'mouseover':fMouseOver,
    'mouseout':fMouseOut,
    'mouseup':fMouseUp,
    'mousedown':fMouseDown,
    });
});

    // Event Functions
function fMouseOver(e){ 
    if (this.id == 'menuButton') {
        //do something
    }
     if (this.className == 'bigButton') {        
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would that solve the problem? OP says the function is called successfully if the switch statement is removed from its body.

Comment: "this function is not trigger"

Comment: "but when i omit the switch condition i can trigger the function."

Answer (score 0):

Try `switch(page) {..}` instead. Leave the `var pager = page;` out.

My guess is that it somehow becomes a "passing by value" situation.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is taking you out of the function. Completely skipping the alert. So the function is actually running, only it is doing it silently.